# Where is libEGL.so in Virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, opengl

I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 guest, but I can't seem to find `libEGL.so` anywhere. Is VirtualBox supposed to install EGL?

Comment: Virtualbox *installs* nothing, Virtualbox *runs* virtual machines. What were you running in Ubuntu that required that library?